# Code First - Two databases same project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I currently have one project which has one database with code migrations enabled.

Meanwhile I need to create another database inside the same project, and I am not sure how to `enable-migrations` to this context.

Or this is not the correct approach? And I should create a new project specifically to this new database?

Thanks

Comment: I think that for the members of SO to be able to provide a good answer, you need to provide much more information.

Comment: If all you want is to create 2 Entity Framework databases inside one project that is possible to do all you have to do is redo the create database code with a different path.

Comment: Given I understood your question right, have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21538091/3129340. It handles migrations of multiple contexts inside the same project.

Answer (score 0):

using this command in visual studio package manager console: Add-Migration yourMigrationClassName -Context yourContextName
and then: update-migration -Context yourContextName

where yourContextName is DbContext class name in your Project and yourMigrationClassName is migration class name you want to create

Comment: You should give more information about your solution. Explain it more clearly so people can understand it.