# ASP.NET MVC deployment with multiple migrations

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-deployment

I've been practicing on MVC programming and now I've reached a place to deploy my web application.

I've tried deploying on local IIS and the only error I found was because of my localDB (probably connection string, that I don't really know what to do about it)

I'd like to know how to edit the connection string and my database for deployment,
and by the way, to know if it's possible to deploy web application with more than one DB migration configs or not? if yes, how? (what should be considered while deploying?

Comment: What have you researched/tried so far?

Comment: I've taken a look on tutorials of deployment on the net, but I couldn't reach my goal.

Comment: You will probably need to be a lot more specific about what you have tried before you will get much help I'm afraid.

Comment: Like I said, so far I've tried deploying on local IIS and the only error I found was because of my localDB, which I tried using another connection, but I need to know "if it is possible to do explicit migration when I have 2 different DbContext and for each I have 2 different migration configuration in my web app?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I found the best solution for my problem.
by
Anthony Chu

[Multiple DB Contexts in the Same DB and Application in EF 6 and Code First Migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537558/multiple-db-contexts-in-the-same-db-and-application-in-ef-6-and-code-first-migra)