# ASP.NET MVC Migration model validation error from Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-migrations

I have ASP.NET MVC application with 2 separate databases. The first database is standard Identity context

```
  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser  {
    public ClaimsIdentity GenerateUserIdentity(ApplicationUserManager manager) {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = manager.CreateIdentity(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUserManager manager)  {
        return Task.FromResult(GenerateUserIdentity(manager));
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> {
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("ApplicationConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false) { }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create() {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

second context

```
 public class TestModel : DbContext {
    public TestModel()
        : base("Connection") {
    }
    public virtual DbSet<A> As { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<B> Bs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<C> Cs { get; set; }
```

}

I successfully enabled migration for TestModel and try to run

```
add-migration Initial -ConfigurationTypeName project.Migrations.TestMigrations.Configuration
```

which results in the error

```
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

project.Models.Tests.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

project.Models.Tests.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.

IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.
```

I was not able to find anything related to this problem and appreciate any help here.
Thank you.

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531201/entitytype-identityuserlogin-has-no-key-defined-define-the-key-for-this-entit

Comment: Thank you for the link but it does not resolve the iddue. I have no problem running migrations on ApplicationDbContext where Identity belongs. The problem occurs when I create migration on second context which suppose to have no connections Identity and there are no classes "Models.Tests.IdentityUserLogin" and "Models.Tests.IdentityUserRole" in this model. Somehow EF gets it from ApplicationDbContext and I cannot figure out how to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: Do any of the models in the second context have a reference to the Identity Models? Also, [have you enabled migrations for each context?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537558/multiple-db-contexts-in-the-same-db-and-application-in-ef-6-and-code-first-migra)

Comment: None. Classes A, B, and C in the second context just regular classes like

Comment: public int ID {get; set;} , public string Name {get;set;} and nothing more.

Comment: Each context has own migration.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the primary and foreigner key constraint in both database. First repair identity constraint by connecting both database individually. For Migration you can use replication as well. Hope this hint will help you.