# How to add new table in sql server

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-migrations

I already created a Asp.net core web api project and have created a database using identity with migration. Now I need to know, that can I add new table to the database and how can i do that? I'm new to this field.

I also have tried `Add-Migration` but giving me error. I have no idea about this.

The error message is:

> An error occurred while accessing the IWebHost on class 'Program'.
>   Continuing without the application service provider. Error:
>   AddEntityFrameworkStores can only be called with a user that derives
>   from IdentityUser. More than one DbContext was found. Specify
>   which one to use. Use the '-Context' parameter for PowerShell commands
>   and the '--context' parameter for dotnet commands.

Comment: You've got 2 contexts so you need to parameterize your commands. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537558/multiple-db-contexts-in-the-same-db-and-application-in-ef-6-and-code-first-migra).

Answer (score 0):

Create your model and add in DB context.

```
public DbSet<UserAttachment> UserAttachment {get; set;}
```

After that

```
add-migration
```

And then

```
update-database
```

Comment: Tried this. But giving me error....{An error occurred while accessing the IWebHost on class 'Program'. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: AddEntityFrameworkStores can only be called with a user that derives from IdentityUser<TKey>.
More than one DbContext was found. Specify which one to use. Use the '-Context' parameter for PowerShell commands and the '--context' parameter for dotnet commands.}

Comment: error is saying the more than one dbcontext found please make sure to use only one.

Comment: ok. I tried to add two DBContext. now i deleted those files and lines added. Is there any way to add new table with help of old migration?

Comment: delete you migration folder and try to make new db context file and add migration again

Comment: delete the folder with cmd? or by right click - delete?

Comment: Hey, Can you help me? I need to create two tables, but I have already created one table with migration. Is there anyway we can add new table to same database through that old migration

Comment: yes add another dbset in dbcontext and add-migration after that update-databse

Comment: when i done that only i get that error that i mentioned above

Comment: please provide screenshot or code in regmi.sudesh098@gmail.com

Comment: have mailed you. please check it