# Multi database login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, code-first

I know this is repeated question and even here but I have tried all solutions without no sense. I have the main DB where the user check if found and return by his own or related database that should change the connection string to be current used one. My problem is that despite it's got the database correct but a `dbcontext` works on the main database it diverts again I don't why.

My `applicationdbcontext` is

```
public ApplicationDbContext(string connectionString)
           : base(string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString) ? "DefaultConnection" : connectionString, throwIfV1Schema: false)
{
    this.Database.CommandTimeout = 600;
}

public static ApplicationDbContext Create(string dbCatlogConn)
{
    return new ApplicationDbContext(ConString.dbCatlogConn);
}
```

and this is my public class

```
public class ConString
{
    public static string dbCatlogConn { get; set; }
}
```

This is my login in accountcontroller class

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl, string language = Config.DefaultLanguage)
{
    try
    {
        System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.Validate();
    }
    catch
    {
        return RedirectToRoute("Login", new { language, returnUrl });
    }

    dbName = model.username;

    Session["dbName"] = dbName;
    var dbname = db.SchoolLists
                   .Where(t => (t.dbname == dbName))
                   .Select(t => new { ConnString = t.ConnectionString }).ToList();

    // new conection
    dbConnectionString = "";
    Session["ConnectionString"] = dbConnectionString;
    db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    UserManager.PasswordHasher = new CustomPasswordHasher();

    bool CheckConnResult = db.Database.Exists();

    // code here
    var user = db.Users.Where(e => e.UserName.ToLower() == model.UserName.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault();
    var result = new SignInStatus();

    if (user == null)
        result = SignInStatus.Failure;
    else
    {
        string dbPassword = dal.DecryptPassword(user.AnotherUsername, user.AnotherSalt, user.PasswordHash);
        var status = UserManager.PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(dbPassword, model.Password);

        if (status == PasswordVerificationResult.Success)
            // error here
            result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, user.PasswordHash, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
            // result = SignInStatus.Success;
        else
            result = SignInStatus.Failure;
    }

    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
                if (user != null)
                {
                    if (user.Disabled == true)
                    {
                        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", language == "Invalid login attempt.");
                        // rest the connection to default
                        // = ConString.Mainbd;
                        return View(model);
                        //return View("Lockout");
                    }
                    else
                    {


                    }
                }

                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);

            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");

            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });

            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", language == "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
}
```

I try also to change `applicationdbcontext` create in a startup file

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => ApplicationDbContext.Create(ConString.dbCatlogConn));
```

but the `ApplicationSignInManager` always uses the main connection - it doesn't update for the new one after login despite I got the connection string correctly

Comment: Is there any solution suggested?

Comment: Have you tried using multiple dbContexts ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537558/multiple-db-contexts-in-the-same-db-and-application-in-ef-6-and-code-first-migra

Comment: It is only change connection I think it is too simple but there is sometsomething which revert to the old connection

Answer (score -1):

Could you please try by creating a configure like below?  and then change the connection string dynamically.

```
public static class ApplicationDbContextConfigurer
{
    public static void Configure(
        DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext> builder, string connectionString)
    {
        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    }

    public static void Configure(
        DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext> builder, DbConnection connection)
    {
        builder.UseSqlServer(connection);
    }
}
```

[image]

Change connection string

```
DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext> builder = 
    new DbContextOptionsBuilder<VineforceDbContext>();

ApplicationDbContextConfigurer.Configure(builder, connectionString);
```

Comment: @HarshGupta is it a new class and where I need to add it?

Comment: @mr.alaa: yes, you can create a new class ApplicationDbContextConfigurer and a method in it configure. Whenever you want to change the connections string then you can call this method. just like as shown below.

Comment: SignInManager still save the pervious connection after log out when it try to connect with anew database